# max-width in sub div doesn't work (parent div has flex display)

Tags: css, flexbox

My html code is very simple, just to test the css max-width and flexbox display. My goal is having the button width as 190px, but it doesn't work. If I remove the display css in my .header, it will work. 
Please explain me what is wrong here?
Thanks

Here is my html code:

```css
.header {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #16325C;
  height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.menu {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu > .dropdown {
  display: block;
  max-width: 190px;
}
.menu > .dropdown > button {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #16325C;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="left">
    <li class="menu">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button>
          Text
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` is working, it defines the maximum amount of width that a box can grow. You are searching for `width` because your sentence in the question:

> My goal is having the button width as 190px, but it doesn't work

So try:

```css
.header {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #16325C;
  height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.menu {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu > .dropdown {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
}
.menu > .dropdown > button {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #16325C;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="left">
    <li class="menu">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button>
          Text
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned `display: flex;` to DIV `.header`which means *this* is the flex container and `<ul class="left">`is the only flex item in it, *not the `li` elements in it (direct parent/child relationship). This is probably the (or at least one) cause for your problem.